# Issue in handling Timers

Tags: c#

I have developed an application such that it reads the Voltages from an RPS which is connected to PLC. My program should run continuously for more than 10 hours. But its getting stuck in the middle (It's working for 3 hours and it is also getting stuck within an hour). If any one have some idea please help me out where am I facing Issue.

Comment: You might want to post some code. Otherwise it's hard to tell whats going on...

Answer (score 0):

check out the system power settings ... maybe the hard disk is set to sleep after 1 or 3 hours ... or maybe the systems goes on a stand by ... otherwise check the event log for errors.

Comment: I have changed the system power settings to sleep never and it is not in a stand by mode. I have to check event log.  ThanksVani